# How to start vim without executing /etc/vimrc?

Tags: unix, vim, vimrc

On my Linux server at work, the admins did not install cscope, and I installed it from source in my home directory and added it to the $PATH.  The trouble is, the /etc/vimrc has a reference to /usr/bin/cscope which does not exist and everytime I start vim, it complains about that and I have to press  for that message to go away.

It is interesting that if I remove cscope from my $PATH, I don't get that behavior - so it is possible that vim is testing that cscope exists somewhere, and only then executing the cscope configuration - but then it gets it wrong!

So my question is: can I set something up in my .vimrc so it does not source the global /etc/vimrc?  I don't want to move cscope out of PATH, as I don't want to type the full directory name every time I run it from the command line.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From the [Vim man page](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/vim.html):

```
-u {vimrc}

Use the commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations. All the other
initializations are skipped. Use this to edit a special kind of files.
It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the name "NONE".
See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.
```

If you still want your `~/.vimrc` to be processed, try this:

```
vim -u ~/.vimrc
```

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc` (or your shell's equivalent file if not bash) to have the `-u` switch added automatically:

```
alias vim="vim -u ~/.vimrc"
```

You won't be able to add something to `~/.vimrc` to prevent `/etc/vimrc` from being read, because the system file is processed before your user file (see `:help init`, section 3, "Execute Ex commands, from environment variables and/or files").

Comment: Thanks! This finally allowed me to edit a file that (for some reason) had thousands of characters in one line and would otherwise freeze my Vim for ever.

Answer (score 131):

From the [Vim man page](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/vim.html):

> -u {vimrc}
>
> Use the commands in the file  {vimrc}  for  initializations. 
>   All the other initializations are
>                    skipped.  Use this to edit  a  special  kind  of
>                    files.  It can also be used to skip all initial-
>                    izations by giving the name "NONE".  See  ":help
>                    initialization" within vim for more details.

So this should do the job:

```
vim -u NONE
```

You should be able to alias this to your normal command for everyday usage.

Comment: ... but I want ~/.vimrc to execute, just not /etc/vimrc

Comment: `vim -u ~/.vimrc`