# Why is vim inserting the contents of ". after I leave insert mode

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, buffer

vim is doing something that I can't quite figure out. When I leave insert mode, and navigate with j/k/h/l within a second of doing so, vim appends the contents of the `".` buffer.

On a tip from [How to start vim without executing /etc/vimrc?](https://superuser.com/questions/140913/how-to-start-vim-without-executing-etc-vimrc) I am starting vim with `vim -u NONE testfile`, which should mean I've disabled any weird configuration I might have.

Here is what I do to show the problem:

1. Open up a new, empty file with with `vim -u NONE testfile`.
2. `iTEST<esc>`. I've just inserted the text `TEST` and exited insert mode.
3. `:reg` will show, among other things, `". TEST`. `<enter>` will close the register view.
4. `A<enter>Now I type this<esc>k` and `TEST` is inserted at the end of the line I just typed! My document now looks like:

   `TEST
   Now I type thisTEST`

   and `:reg` shows `". ^@Now I type thisTEST`

But If I had let 2 seconds pass between the `<esc>` and the `k`, the extra text would not have been inserted. **What is going on?**

**edit:** This was a GNU screen issue. I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is a GNU screen issue. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow

Within screen, `C-a : maptimeout 0` solves this. I'll be adding it to my `.screenrc`.

Sanity preserved.